# Dynamically change ReactStrap Navbar

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to change the Navbar Login item to Logout using a global variable (windows.isLoggedOut).  How can I refresh the Navbar?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar,Nav,NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import{Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './customNavBar.css';

const CustomNavBar = () => {
return(
    <div>
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
          <Navbar.Brand>
              TEAMWORKER
          </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    <NavItem eventkey={1} ><Link className="nav-link" 
                          to="/DashBoard">Home</Link></NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventkey={2} ><Link className="nav-link" 
                          to="/help">Help</Link</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventkey={3} ><Link className="nav-link" to="/login" > 
                          {window.isLoggedOut? 'Logout' : 'Login'}</Link></NavItem>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>

    </div>
)
```

};

Comment: Refresh mean you want to change URLs and options right?

Comment: I want to change the Login options ... the URL is changed in another part of code.  I thought if I was able to refresh the NavBar then {window.isLoggedOut? 'Logout' : 'Login'} would work.

Comment: Unless there is another way I should be doing it?

Comment: Looks like nobody has an answer.